# Pointing WebLogic at a Maven Target Directory

Tags: maven, weblogic

My problem: I'm sick of changing a JSP then waiting 3-4 minutes to redeploy to the web server.

What I would LIKE to do is point Weblogic at the Maven target/app directory. Then, when I save a file, I run "mvn war:exploded" and it notices the update but DOESNT redeploy everything, only the file I need.

Right now in my maven POM, I have the war plugin output directory set to the Weblogic autodeploy directory. So, as soon as I run "mvn package", it automatically deploys. However, I have to wait 3-4 minutes for the deploy.

Any advice out there?

Using Weblogic 10.3.6, Maven 3, Eclipse.

Comment: Are you creating an exploded archive directory or deploying a WAR?

Comment: By default, the maven package goal will generate a war in the weblogic domain autodeploy directory. However, I've tried pointing at the exploded directory (via the enterprise console) created during the war creation, but with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a new deployment at the target/$WAR_NAME folder and set Source Accessibility to "I will make the deployment accessible from the following location" (leave the default for the actual location), then running `mvn war:exploded` will update the JSPs in target and WebLogic will pick up the changes.

However, this doesn't seem to work well with redeploying Java class files through `mvn install`.